# C# Update bitmap in picturebox

Tags: c#, performance, bitmap

I'm working on a screen sharing project ,and i recieve a small blocks of image from a `Socket` constantly and need to update them on a certain initial dekstop bitmap i have.

Basically i constantly read data from socket(data which is stored as jpeg image) ,using `Image.FromStream()` to retrieve the image and copying the recieved block pixels to the full primary bitmap(at a specific position `X` and `Y` which i also get from the socket)- that's how the initial image gets updated. But then comes the part where i need to display it on a `Picturebox`
I handle the `Paint` event and redrawing it all again-the entire inital image,which is pretty big(1920X1080 in my case).

This is my code:

```
    private void MainScreenThread()
    {
        ReadData();//reading data from socket.
        initial = bufferToJpeg();//first intial full screen image.
        pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;//activating the paint event.
        while (true)
        {
            int pos = ReadData();
            x = BlockX();//where to draw :X
            y = BlockY();//where to draw :Y
            Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg();//constantly reciving blocks.
            Draw(block, new Point(x, y));//applying the changes-drawing the block on the big initial image.using native memcpy.

            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                pictureBox1.Refresh();//updaing the picturebox for seeing results.
                // this.Text = ((pos / 1000).ToString() + "KB");
            }));
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (initial)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle); //draws at picturebox's bounds
        }
    }
```

Because i'm aiming at high speed performance(it's kind of a real-time project) , i would like to know if there isn't any method to draw current recieved the block itself on the picturebox instead of drawing the whole `initial` bitmap again-which seems very inefficient to me...
This is my drawing method(works extremly fast, copying block with `memcpy`):

```
     private unsafe void Draw(Bitmap bmp2, Point point)
    {
        lock (initial)
        {  
            BitmapData bmData = initial.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, initial.Width, initial.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, initial.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;
            int Width = bmp2.Width;
            int Height = bmp2.Height;
            int X = point.X;
            int Y = point.Y;

            scan0 = IntPtr.Add(scan0, stride * Y + X * 3);//setting the pointer to the requested line
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                memcpy(scan0, scan02 ,(UIntPtr)(Width * 3));//copy one line

                scan02 = IntPtr.Add(scan02, stride2);//advance pointers
                scan0 = IntPtr.Add(scan0, stride);//advance pointers//
            }


            initial.UnlockBits(bmData);
            bmp2.UnlockBits(bmData2);
        }
    }
```

Here are some examples of a full primary bitmap,and other small blocks i'm getting and need to draw over the full one.

**Full bitmap:**
[image: full bitmap]
**small block:**

[image]
**small block:**

[image]

**small block:**

[image]

I'm getting  large amount of small blocks per second(30~40) somtimes their bounds are really small(rectangle of 100X80 pixels for example) so redrawing the entire bitmap again is not necessary...Rapidly Refreshing a full screen image would kill the performance...

I hope my explaination was clear.

Looking forward for an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use `Control.CreateGraphics` to get the graphics from the picture box and then draw on top of it with `Graphics.DrawImage(image, x, y)` so you avoid redrawing the intial image. But I don't know how efficient it is, it might be blitting it anyway under the hood. Might be worth doing some performance testing.

Comment: Change the pixel format of the image to 32bppPArgb, it renders 10 times faster than all the other ones.  Ensure the image never has to be rescaled to fit the picturebox, ClientRectangle doesn't help at all.  Never use Refresh, use Invalidate(Rectangle) instead where the rectangle is the part of the image that actually has to be redrawn.

Comment: @Hans Passant  the images I'm getting are jpeg. .. (24bpprgb ).. I have to display the images  scaled..it's for a screen sharing purpose..so if someone has a 1920X1080 resolution,  and he's sharing the screen to someone who has 1600X880 resolution the client won't be able to see the entire screen...If the image is bigger then he's computer resolution it won't be possible to see the whole image ;) so I think stretching is must do be done here. For properly displaying of the screen.

Comment: @Hans Passant about the rest of your answer,  I'll try and reply tomorrow.  Time to sleep a little bit :)

Comment: @Slashy do you need to clear the canvas or you just need to draw on top?

Comment: @Unit only draw on top.

Comment: Did you consider running this code through a profiler? It typically makes it very easy to tweak the performance of an application.

Comment: @Slashy, how about dividing big picture(1920X1080) to small regions(many PictureBoxes) and update small regions, not the big picture?

Comment: @Slashy, also did you try Invalidate() with Rectangle (updated region) instead of .Refresh()?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen i haven't worked with a profiler before,but does it proves anything else that the `queryperformancecounter` or the  `StopWatch` class don't provide?(sorry for the question, i just never worked with that before)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan not realistic..i cant do somthing like that haha. it have to be dynamic picturebox(in the resizing context). about th invalidate-i'll try it..didn't know this method has an overload..

Comment: @Slashy I actually think it might. There is one inbuilt in Visual Studio. Try using it. A profiler is a very commonly used tool when building performance-demanding apps.

Comment: My suggestion is to use GDI for the actual painting.  Also, to my eye, if you're already working with pointers then you may as well drop into unsafe rather than working through the IntPtr abstraction.  Pixel24* is much more clear than IntPtr *= 3 and all.

Comment: @hoodaticus `GDI` which means?bitblt?i'm working with `memcpy` for one and only reason:it works way faster than using then using the pointers  directly..dont ask me why..memcpy works extremly fast....according to my benchmarks-somthing between 7-7.5x faster... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be shame to leave that question without some answer. The following is about 10 times faster in my tests when updating small portions of the picture box. What it does basically is *smart invalidating* (invalidates just the updated portion of the bitmap, considering the scaling) and *smart painting* (draws only the invalidated portion of the picture box, taken from `e.ClipRectangle` and considering the scaling):

```
private Rectangle GetViewRect() { return pictureBox1.ClientRectangle; }

private void MainScreenThread()
{
    ReadData();//reading data from socket.
    initial = bufferToJpeg();//first intial full screen image.
    pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;//activating the paint event.
    // The update action
    Action<Rectangle> updateAction = imageRect =>
    {
        var viewRect = GetViewRect();
        var scaleX = (float)viewRect.Width / initial.Width;
        var scaleY = (float)viewRect.Height / initial.Height;
        // Make sure the target rectangle includes the new block
        var targetRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(
            (int)Math.Truncate(imageRect.X * scaleX),
            (int)Math.Truncate(imageRect.Y * scaleY),
            (int)Math.Ceiling(imageRect.Right * scaleX),
            (int)Math.Ceiling(imageRect.Bottom * scaleY));
        pictureBox1.Invalidate(targetRect);
        pictureBox1.Update();
    };

    while (true)
    {
        int pos = ReadData();
        x = BlockX();//where to draw :X
        y = BlockY();//where to draw :Y
        Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg();//constantly reciving blocks.
        Draw(block, new Point(x, y));//applying the changes-drawing the block on the big initial image.using native memcpy.

        // Invoke the update action, passing the updated block rectangle
        this.Invoke(updateAction, new Rectangle(x, y, block.Width, block.Height));
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    lock (initial)
    {
        var viewRect = GetViewRect();
        var scaleX = (float)initial.Width / viewRect.Width;
        var scaleY = (float)initial.Height / viewRect.Height;
        var targetRect = e.ClipRectangle;
        var imageRect = new RectangleF(targetRect.X * scaleX, targetRect.Y * scaleY, targetRect.Width * scaleX, targetRect.Height * scaleY);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, targetRect, imageRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
```

The only kind of tricky part is determining the scaled rectangles, especially the one for invalidating, due to floating point to int conversions required, so we make sure it's eventually a little bigger than needed, but not less.

Comment: i see kind of many coruptted pixels..wait.. i suposed to replace the `image` variable in your answer  to `initial` or to `block`?

Comment: and i dont see the point.. your **still** redrawing the full `initial` image...  here
`e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, targetRect, imageRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`

Comment: (1) Sorry, `image` was supposed to be `initial` variable. (2) No, this overload only draws part of the image - imageRect.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k4vsA5) with my test. Copy/paste it to a new WinForms project, then play with `testRect` size or `pb_Paint` (comment everything and uncomment the last line to see the difference with partial vs full image draw).

Comment: awesome! it works 2x~3x faster! just few things that i would like to understand :1) can you give a short explaination about the `invlidate` method?is it redrawing a region? i'm not sure about it :)  2)you just calcuated the scaling factor in the paint event right?3) not very necessary but if you have even some micro optimizations for this, i would like to see. after all i want the best performance :)
thank you so so much.

Comment: (1) Invalidate has a good explanation in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dtk06x2(v=vs.110).aspx): *Invalidates the specified region of the control (adds it to the control's update region, which is the area that will be repainted at the next paint operation), and causes a paint message to be sent to the control.* and then in **Remarks:** *Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the Invalidate method.*

Comment: (2) Yes I did. Also the inverse scaling factors inside the update action. (3) No, I haven't, all I did before posting the answer was playing with the code you see in the fiddle.

Comment: alright! and how to do you get the control updatd region in th paint event? is that the e.ClipRectangle part line?

Comment: Exactly. Even if you try to draw outside that rectangle, it will be clipped anyway, so this is what I call *smart painting*.

Comment: it's intreseting me how the `DrawImage` is implemented...the `Graphics` class of microsoft..i was wondering if i can do a little faster implemenetion of it

Comment: You can't see the actual implementation because the `DrawImage` is a simple wrapper to the corresponding Gdi+ method. And Gdi+ is written in unmanaged C++ and I don't think source code is available.

Comment: alright!thank you so so much you have no idea how much that helped :)

Comment: You are welcome :) If I find something faster, I'll let you know. Happy coding!

Comment: i would like to hear :) Thanks again!

Comment: was looking around...would it be posibble to implement that with the native `bitblt` method?scroll down to the `OnPaint` event-they used this method to draw instead of `DrawImage()`
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/BitBlt.html

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but looks like it does not support scaling. I can't recall if it will work if setting source and/or target transform.

Comment: i kept playing with the invalide and update code..it seems like there still an update for the whole bitmap eventhough i used `Invalidate(Rectangle)` only for a specific area..i just drawed above the bitmap for the it's full bounds, i expected to see only the `testRect` area changed to green and the rest still remains blue(eventhough i drawed the entire bitmap) because in the `OnPaint` event only that specific region gets updated! so visually i should see only the red rectangle changes into green,and the rest blue area should stay.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/pssVe9

Comment: maybe i'm doing somthing wrong? sorry for the many questions.. i really aprpeciate your help :).
Notice i havent used the scaling method because i just don't need if for this test.

Comment: What you need to know is that the `e.ClipRectangle` inside the Paint event is not always the one that you used for `Invalidate` call. For instance, the first time picture box is painted, it will contain the whole client rectangle. Also if you resize the form / picture box, then again it could be different. This is basically how Windows works. What is important to you is to minimize redraw regions forced by your bitmap updates.

Comment: hey! long time but i'm still looking for a minor small improvments for this,correct me if i wrong,but after calling the `Invalidate()` method here  `pictureBox1.Invalidate(targetRect);` ,the         `pictureBox1.Update();` line is unnecessary,since the `Invalidate()`  method also causes a paint message to be sent to the control,which means it would trigger the Paint event automatically. am i right?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx @Ivan Stoev

Comment: That's correct. I've put it in order to test the speed of the whole operation including the `DrawBitmap`. There is no technical need to force the immediate applying the `Invalidate`d region, so you can remove the `Update` call and let it repaint when Windows decides.

Comment: hey!
seems like i won't  stop bothering you in the next 5 years :)
after few steps of development, i'm using a different approach for the data processing in my project.
As written before,it's a screen sharing project. a short explaination: each package sent from the server to the client contains the changesd area(as jpeg bitmap) which need to be applied on the source image in the client side.
your solution was perfect for the previous approach,where i read each region ,apply the changes on the source image and draw it,but now actually each package contain **few** areas

Comment: Lol :) Happy New Year!

Comment: And i honestly think reading each area,Locking the source bitmap's bits, appying the changes and redrawing it again(not before unlocking it of course ) could be very not efficient.
so i first of all read all the regions,apply the changes by locking/unlocking bitmap only once( per whole package recieved),and then using invalidate but this time i have to invalidate the **whole screen*,since many regions changed,and the invalidation is done only when the entire buffer read and whole changed areas are applied to the source image. 
I hope i explained the problem well.... :)

Comment: Is there still a way to invalidate only the changed areas?(but only once ! after the whole areas applied.

for example,  for a package contains 4 changed rectangles what i done before is:

1.read area-->lockBits() --> apply changes --> unlockBits() --> invalidate(area)( which caused to the picturebox to repaint immediently).

now the approach is
1.for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   read area,apply changes(when i say apply i mean only copy it's pixels(using unsafe pointers) .
2.only then need to redraw,but this time,the whole screen.

i know it's quite long,but i hope you got the doubt...

Comment: and happy new year :):)

Comment: Now on the subject. Unfortunately this optimization will not work because the clip rectangle will be a union of the invalidated rectangles. And there is no other optimization I can think of. The graphics has so called `Clip` region, but I don't know a way to decompose it on rectangles. The only way I see is after applying the changes, do `Invalidate` followed immediately by `Update` **for each** changed rectangle.

Comment: oh...i understand..but triggering the paint for each area.. could be also slower..i think i'll just invalidate each area after applying changes..and in the end i'll force the Paint event using 'Update()'...(even thought it would be a union and contain few extra pixels..guess i'll have to measure these 2 approaches.)
by the way...somthing i've never actually understood,when i use `Invalidate()` it does not trigger the paint event immediately right? so when does it paint it?(in a case there is no `Update()` call later).

Thank you so so much. I really appreciate your help

Comment: When you do `Invalidate`, the corresponding rectangle is added to the invalidated window region, and `WM_PAINT` message is *posted* to the window. Later on it is processed by the `WndProc` which triggers `Paint` event. The trick is that the paint messages are always kept at the end of the message queue, so they are processed after all other messages, thus keeping the repaints at minimum. So event if there are hundreds of invalidates, normally they cause a single paint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132097/discussion-between-slashy-and-ivan-stoev).

Comment: yeah..but when you use `Update()`... you force the repainting...so i think i should use one `Update()` after the whole `Invalidate()` calls..(after read and process the entire regions in the buffers)...

One last though someone suggestted to me..to check out the WPF platform..since winForms doe's not intended to extremly fast drawing.. eventhough it works fine right now :) @Ivan Stoev

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to draw on top of the canvas, you can draw the **initial** image just once and then use `CreateGraphics()` and `DrawImage` to update the content:

```
ReadData();
initial = bufferToJpeg();
pictureBox1.Image = initial;
var graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
while (true)
{
    int pos = ReadData();
    Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg();
    graphics.DrawImage(block, BlockX(), BlockY());
}
```

I'll update the answer with a performance comparison as I'm not convinced this will give any major benefit; it will, at least, avoid a double **DrawImage** though.

Comment: @Slashy: I was assuming the `Draw` method was drawing the image to the picture box, that's why I thought it was invoked twice. I'm not sure what you mean by "corrupted pixels" that are shown, it works fine in my test. A note on your code is that the lock is probably the most time consuming part.

Comment: I see what you mean: you are drawing the images and then changing the `SizeMode`? If so I wouldn't expect it to work as `Graphics` blit images just ones, it doesn't persist your changes so if you resize the PB, you'll have to redraw everything from scratch. You might want to have a look at some third party controls, WinForms are not ideal for custom graphics.

Comment: Then I wouldn't rely on the `SizeMode` for drawing, I would just strech the image and then draw it and leave it to normal. But I still think WinForms PictureBox is not the right tool for this.