# C# Draw on image using unsafe pointers

Tags: c#, pointers, bitmap

I'm trying to set few pixels in a bitmap using unsafe pointer access(for performance boost)-this is my code:

```
 private unsafe void DrawImage(Bitmap bmp1) 
 {
  BitmapData bmData = bmp1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp1.PixelFormat);
  IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
  int stride = bmData.Stride;
  int x = 200;
  int y = 400;

  for (; y < 600; y++) {
   byte * p = (byte * ) scan0.ToPointer();
   p += y * stride + x * 4;


   for (; x < 900; x++) {

    p[0] = 0; //blue
    p[1] = 0; //green
    p[2] = 255; //red              
    p += 4;
   }

  }

  bmp1.UnlockBits(bmData);

 }
```

As you can see,i'm trying to set a block (to red color) from  **y=400** to **y=600** , and **x=200** to **x=900**.
On every interation of the outer loop i advance the pointer to the desired address ,but i'm getting only a "thin" horizontal line of red pixels...which indicated that somthing is wrong with the `y` address..i can't get why.

`p += y * stride + x * 4;`-this is how i advance the pointer everytime... did i miss something?

i hope my question was clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HansPassant that's the point..i dont want to set the entire bitmap ...only a particular region...leave the pixelformat now.this is not  the problem... `x*4` would advance the pointer to the x position everytime the program enters the outer loop .*4 because it's 4 bytes per pixels right now(32bpprgb)

Comment: 200x700 is more than __a few__ pixels amd may well be reason to use the regulare GDI+ FillRectangle method.

Comment: @TaW it was just an example.. it could also be 100X100.. please.. and it's not only setting the pixel to red...i gave a small shorten exampl from somthing i'm wokring on...so it's necessary to use unsafe pointers here.i'll have to do some proccessing

Comment: You made the hard assumption that it is 32bpp.  That's risky, could work.  But then the mistake you made is only set 3 byte values.  The alpha channel is not set, if it 0 then you won't see the pixel.  This code is *not* faster than FillRectangle(), GDI+ does not suck that bad.

Comment: @HansPassant i dont want to change the alpha channel.
again, i don't understand why you treat to this part of the question.
this is only a minor example,not close to what i'm trying to achieve..
i cant just draw rectangle using FillRectangle...this is not what i'm intending for.
In my project i have 2 bitmap,one big and one smaller,and the smaller one contains delta values-which i need to xor with the bigger image-so again the proccessing is necessary  here... i have to xor each byte using the unsafe pointers..i'm not going to use `GetPixel` `SetPixel`.

Comment: You should have told us a little about these later goals of yours in the question, so we would have known why you go for the lockbits/unsafe method!

Comment: @TaW yeah..i'm  sorry for that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The shortcuts in your loops don't go well together. At least the inner loop needs a proper start value. Best to set both start and end values; most likely you will want to go for a rectangle later anyway..
- Also, as Hans noted you should make sure to look into the pixel widths of your actual `PixelFormat`.
- Finally the loop advances are not correct.

This should work:

```
    private unsafe void DrawImage(Bitmap bmp1)
    {
        BitmapData bmData = bmp1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height), 
                                          System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
                            bmp1.PixelFormat);

        // this is only a rather incomplete test, of course:
        int pixWidth = bmp1.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb ? 3 :
                   bmp1.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb ? 4 : 4;

        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        int x0 = 100;
        int y0 = 100;
        int x1 = 200;
        int y1 = 300;

        byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer() + y0 * stride;
        for (int y = y0; y < y1; y++)
        {
            p += stride;

            int px = x0 * pixWidth;
            for (int x = x0; x < x1; x++)
            {
                px += pixWidth;
                p[px + 0] = 0;   //blue
                p[px + 1] = 0; //green
                p[px + 2] = 255; //red   
            }
        }
        bmp1.UnlockBits(bmData);
    }
```

As noted this is not really a performance boost over GDI+ `FillRectangle`. However if you want to set not a block of pixels and/or not set all to one fixed color only, your code will make sense..

Comment: that's exactly what i need. i need to do some fast proccessing operation such as `xor`ing bitmaps in c#...do you know any even faster way? i'd be glad to hear more ideas! :) .
or that's the fastest rendering could be done in c#? @Taw

Comment: That is pretty much as fast as it get, I'd say. (I changed it a little to get rid of the multiplications in the inner loops.. one is left but these are really just 'microoptimizations'). The processing of the are probably the more interesting targets..

Comment: alright.thank you so so much. i really appreciate the help.
would you mind to try help in something similar to this? it's another question i've asked here on SO..it's about image rendering too..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416132/c-sharp-update-bitmap-in-picturebox
asked like 2 weeks ago.
i'm looking for solutions and i'm kind of  desperate haha

Comment: anway realy realy thanks for the aamzing explained answer.@TaW